# Как проверить существует ли улица?

Tags: python, поиск-api

Я хочу сделать бота который будет проверять существует ли улица которую ему напишут.
Например я пишу боту: Красная пл., Москва, 109012.
А он проверят существует ли эта улица на карте.
Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

В рамках решения подобных задач существуют **прямое геокодирование**, когда введённый адрес преобразовывается в координаты. API геокодеров предусматривают вариант, когда введённый адрес может не существовать, поэтому будут выдавать ошибку, что можно использовать в вашем случае.

Среди популярных API выделю следующие — отсортированы в порядке убывания точности для адресов России:

1. [Геокодер Яндекс.Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/) (до 1000 запросов в сутки)
2. [Геокодер 2GIS](https://docs.2gis.com/ru/api/search/geocoder/overview) (оговариваются отдельно)
3. [Геокодирование Google Карт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview?hl=ru) (ежемесячно предоставляются бонусные кредиты на запросы)
4. [Nominatim от OpenStreetMap](https://nominatim.org/) (полностью бесплатный)

Учтите, что каждая из платформ имеет свои ограничения по количеству и частоте запросов на бесплатных тарифах для тестирования и пет-проектов — я указал их в скобках. Поэтому для коммерческой разработки лучше в дальнейшем приобрести API-ключ с расширенным доступом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно загрузить ФИАС или КЛАДР к себе в базу и сверять по нему вплоть до номера квартиры. Но скорее всего форму ввода адреса придётся разбить на шаги: город, улица, дом.

https://github.com/MrPROtS/pg_fias

https://github.com/asyncee/fias2pgsql